# How to determine if a sample is within a standard deviation of a multivariate normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, standard-deviation, multivariate-normal-distribution

In the case of a sample from a one dimensional normal distribution $x \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma)$, I can calculate whether or not a sample is within some multiple $\eta$ of $\sigma$ by measuring if x is outside of $\mu \pm \eta\sigma$.

How about the case of a MVN? How can I make the same measurement? Specifically, given...

$$
\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix} \sim
\mathcal{N}\Big(
  \begin{bmatrix}\mu_1 \\ \mu_2\end{bmatrix},
  \begin{bmatrix}\sigma_{11} & \sigma_{12} \\ \sigma_{21} & \sigma_{22}\end{bmatrix}
\Big)
$$

How can I calculate if $\mathbf{x}$ is within $\pm\eta\Sigma$?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The usual metric to use here is the [scaled Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance):

$$S(\mathbf{x}) \equiv \frac{D(\mathbf{x})}{\sqrt{n}} = \sqrt{\frac{(\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu})^\text{T} \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} (\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu})}{n}}.$$

If we let $\mathbf{\Sigma}^{1/2}$ denote the multivariate "standard deviation matrix" (i.e., the [principal square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#Positive_semidefinite_matrices) of the variance matrix) then this distance can be written in alternative form as:

$$S(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{||\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1/2} (\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu})||}{\sqrt{n}},$$

which is a scaled version of the norm of the standardised vector (with scaling adjusting to remove the effect on the norm from the number of elements in the vector).  This measure has a few useful properties that make it a good measure of standardised distance from the mean.  In particular, in the special case where $n=1$ you get $S(\mathbf{x}) = |x - \mu|/\sigma$, which is the absolute standardised distance from the mean.  (Consequently, you get $x = \mu \pm S(\mathbf{x}) \sigma$ in this special case.)  The broader distance measure generalises the univariate notion of the standardised distance from the sample mean in a way that accounts for the variance and covariance in the variance matrix, and the length of the random vector.

Using the scaled Mahalanobis distance you can compute whether or not the value $\mathbf{x}$ lies within an elliptical region centred on the mean vector within a particular scaled distance $r$.  This region can be determined as:

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{X}(r) 
&\equiv \{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n | S(\mathbf{x}) \leqslant r \} \\[6pt]
&= \{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n | S(\mathbf{x})^2 \leqslant r^2 \} \\[6pt]
&= \{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n | (\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu})^\text{T} \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} (\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu}) \leqslant n r^2 \}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

In the case of normal data you have $S(\mathbf{X}) \sim \text{Chi}(n)/\sqrt{n}$ using the [chi distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution), so it is possible to compute the probability of lying in one of these regions for a specific value of $r$.  Specifically, you get:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X \in \mathscr{X}(r))
&= \mathbb{P}(S(\mathbf{X}) \leqslant r) \\[16pt]
&= \int \limits_0^{r} \text{Chi}(s|n) \ ds \\[6pt]
&= \frac{2 (n/2)^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)} \int \limits_0^{r} s^{n-1} \exp \Big( - \frac{n s^2}{2} \Big) \ ds. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Comment: hmm ok. Then does a scaled Malahanobis distance of 1, 2, 3, ... correspond directly to standard deviations or have I missed something?

Comment: As you can see from the special case where $n=1$, the scaled Mahalanobis distance corresponds directly to distances in standard deviations in that case.  Consequently, the more general distance measure *generalises* this univariate measure.

Comment: I'm a little slow sometimes so I just want to be sure I have this clearly... In the multivariate case I can take the scaled Malahanobis distance from the mean and it will correspond to the univariate standard deviation and all assumptions about confidence intervals that go along with $\sigma$ are still intact?

Comment: You have not previously mentioned any confidence intervals or assumptions about same, so that is not possible for me to answer.

Comment: The assumption would be that 1, 2, 3 stds corresponds to roughly 68%, 95%, and 99% confidence intervals, does that still hold?

Comment: That no longer holds for $n>1$.  The relevant probability coverage can be obtained by using the chi distribution (or chi-squared distribution) using the above results.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, $S(\mathbf{X}) \sim \text{Chi}(n)/\sqrt{n}$ follows a [Nakagami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakagami_distribution)$(n/2, 1)$-distribution (shape/spread-parametrization). $n$ being the dimension of the normal distribution.

Comment: Yes, that looks right.  Those are closely related distributions.

Comment: Just to give a numerical example, take $n=2$. If I'm correct, then there is a 95%/99% probability that $S(\mathbf{x})$ is within $1.73$ and $2.15$, respectively. For $n=1$, these values are $1.96$ and $2.58$, as expected.

Comment: "In particular, in the special case where n=1 you get S(x)=|x−μ|/σ, so that x=μ±S(x)σ." We also have the case where n is allowed to vary but $\SIgma$ is diagonal, in which case the metric is the distance along each coordinate weighted by the reciprocal of the std. Or, in other words, it's the sum in quadrature of the z-scores, divided by the length of the vector consisting of n 1's.